# USB folder hider/revealer

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, hidden-file

My dad recently gave me this 7 GB key shaped USB. The USB is really cool, but as a user of a 2TB SSD, I don't really need it.

Seeing that it looks like a key, I was wondering how to conceal a folder on my computer that is only revealed when the key shaped USB is plugged into my computer. In other words folder doesn't exist until top secret USB key is plugged into computer. Is there a way to do this?

The folder I'm wanting to hide isn't that important, so encryption isn't what I'm looking for. Just kinda the cool factor (read gimmick) and being able to hide my folders

Edit: I was able to find sort of what I wanted. It is called the ROG keystone and it unlocks a secret drive when plugged into the laptop. Is there any way to replicate this with a normal USB?

[image]

Comment: Instead of using "hiding techniques" just us a proper encryption software like VeraCrypt or if your Windows version contains Bitlocker feature use Bitlocker to go. Then your "secret folders" will only be accessible after entering the correct password.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough, but I don't really care about encryption. What I want is just a way to hide the folders until the USB is plugged in but still have the folders on my laptop because the USB is only 7 GB

Answer (score 1):

It is really not possible to hide a folder on a computer that is not detectable at all unless external tools are required. You can encrypt a folder and have the decryption key be on the usb stick, but the folder itself will be visible.

You would need something like TrueCrypt to create a file storage container that requires a file to open, and store the file on the USB stick.

If the data you are trying to hide is not too large, you could make it much easier to just move the data to the USB stick itself. Then it is really gone from the harddisk.

This does mean that anyone that has the stick has the data too. You could use something like TrueCrypt and create the password protected chamber on the USB stick itself and require a passphrase or store its key on your computer. That way, you still keep the usbkey connected to the computer.

Comment: Ok, what if I removed the "not detectable" restriction? Maybe I can just use hidden folders that are built into windows

Comment: My point is, that it is really easy to see the folders either with a scan, program or clicking a few buttons. So it will bring more hassle than there is gain.

Comment: Aw, ok :( then I guess

Answer (score 1):

This command will make a folder "super-hidden":

```
attrib +r +a +s +h C:\MyHiddenFolder
```

Applying these attributes to a folder will hide it (assuming the user hasn't unticked "hide protected operating system files" in explorer view settings).

You could use the Task Scheduler to execute a batch file to add/remove these folder attributes triggered by the device specific add/remove event.
For the event to appear in Event Viewer you need to enable the event logging for that function first (See [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-track-down-usb-flash-drive-usage-in-windows-10s-event-viewer/)).  The event can then be seen at this path:

```
Application and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > DriverFrameworks-UserMode > Operational
```

You will need to create a custom XML filter to capture the right event for your device.

Example of USB Device connected XML Filter:
(Note that you must escape the & with `&amp;`)

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational">
*[System[EventID=2101]]
and
*[UserData[UMDFHostDeviceRequest[InstanceId='SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&amp;VEN_GENERIC&amp;PROD_FLASH_DISK&amp;REV_8.07#12F9600A&amp;0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}']]]
and
*[UserData[UMDFHostDeviceRequest[RequestMinorCode='20']]]
</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Lastly, if you have the folder in view it will initially just appear to "grey out" until the folder view is refreshed. You can force this with the following cmd line:

```
ie4uinit.exe -show
```